# Сохранение файла через диалоговое окно

Tags: php, javascript, html, download

Подскажите, как сохранить выбранный в диалоговом окне файл через input file, если не предоставляется полный путь к этому файлу? Файл нужно выбрать на клиенте через диалоговое окно и сохранить на сервер

Comment: Не понятен вопрос, где выбран, и в какое поле нужно. Вообще есть поле с типом `file` оно решает половину проблем

Comment: Где вы хотите сохранить выбранный файл?

Comment: Дополнил вопрос

Comment: для `<input type="file">` не требуется полный путь. Вы выбрали файл, отправили на сервер. На сервере файл сохраняется во временной директории и ваш скрипт на сервере волен делать с ним что хочет